# What is the sync interval of Google fit data with their backend servers ( REST api)?

Tags: google-fit

I use Google Fit Rest API to get data about user activities, but the data is different if I look at my app and google fit app at the same time. Everything is synchronized only after a while - sometimes it takes 15 minutes, which is pretty good, but sometimes it can take several hours or even more.

I just want to know how exactly Google Fit synchronizes with the server and is it possible to speed up this process?

Thanks a lot!